# org.jboss.weld.context.NonexistentConversationException: WELD-000321

Tags: java, jsp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pLIn.jpg)I tried to pass a cell value to another page. but it shows error. 
 **1st page:**

```
<tr>
<td><p style="font-size:15pt;margin-left:70px;"><%=resultset.getString("fname") %></p></td>
<td><p style="font-size:15pt;margin-left:70px;"><%=resultset.getString("seats") %></p></td>
<td><input name="cid" value= "<%=resultset.getString("fno")%>"/> </td>
<td> <form method="post" action="booking.jsp"> <input type="submit" value="go"/>
```

I tried to take value using "**request.getParameter("cid")** "

But, when i click that button "**go**" from 1st page it shows error **org.jboss.weld.context.NonexistentConversationException: WELD-000321**

Comment: are you using jboss and jsf? If you are using session then please add that code too.

Comment: nop.. not using jboss and jsf.

Comment: Then which server are you using? the exception says jboss exception.

Comment: glass fish server

Comment: please add your entire exception stack.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in `<td>` as below, it looks like a syntax error:

```
<td><a href="booking.jsp?cid='<%=resultset.getString("fno")%>'">gg</a></td>
```

OR

```
<td><a href="booking.jsp?cid=<%=resultset.getString("fno")%>">gg</a></td>
```

Comment: you are creating a form without submit functionality. what's the use of it?

Comment: it is a table wich shows some flight lists.. i need the ID of flight which user selects. help me with this... pls